# How to delete some of the observations in a column?

Tags: dataset, sas

I have a dataset like this:

```
id
3408
3408
3485
4592
4932
5345
5345
5345
5844
5844
5844
```

I only want to keep the ids that appear 3 times (i.e., `keep id=5345 and id=5844`) and delete the rest. How do I achieve this in SAS? My data are sorted by `id` in order. I want to keep all three duplicated IDs in output dataset

Comment: @monkey if you have an issue and would like to update your question, you can associate your stats.stackexchange.com account with a StackOverflow one. Suggesting an edit is not the way to go and you also won't be able to accept an answer. Good luck, and welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PROC FREQ will get you this directly.

```
proc freq data=myid;
tables id/out=threeobs(keep=count id where=(count=3));
run;
```

Use >= instead of = if you mean 3 or more.
Based on comments, here is an example of merging back to the original data:

```
data have;
input id;
datalines;
3408
3408
3485
4592
4932
5345
5345
5345
5844
5844
5844
;;;;
run;

proc freq data=have;
tables id/out=ids(where=(count=3) keep=id count);
run;

proc sort data=have;
by id;
run;
data want;
merge have(in=h) ids(in=i);
by id;
if i;
run;
```

Comment: The idea is right, but your code contains mistakes. You need to keep the count variable to be able to use it in a where clause. + a where clause needs to hold the condition within brackets. I would still go with cmjohns approach, it's not complex and probably less resource-heavy. (of course, only matters in really large datasets)

Comment: Yeah, too quick coding here :)  Fixed.

Comment: My preference in SAS is to use PROCs when I'm doing something that a PROC is made to do.  It is often faster than a data step (as it is compiled code), and even if not, it's much clearer to other programmers what I'm doing.

Comment: is there a way to keep all three duplicated ids in the output data?

Comment: The easiest way is to just merge this back to the original dataset `by id;`.

Comment: Merge is not working I tried merge by id but it only keeps one if its duplicated

Comment: Edited in an example.

Answer (score 3):

Using PROC SQL, you can `JOIN` and create a new data set, something like this:

```
proc sql;
   create table want as
   select a.*
   from have a
   join (
      select id
      from   have
      group by id
      having count(*) = 3
      ) b
   on b.id=a.id
quit;
```

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't sure if you wanted just a list of ID's that appeared 3 times or all rows who have an id that is replicated 3 times.  If you want the former, the @bellvueBob's code will get you there.

Otherwise, here is one way to just get a list of the ID's that appear in the data set 3 times.  The advantage to this code is small memory usage and speed since the data set is already sorted.

```
data threeobs(keep=id);
  set myid;
  by id;
  if first.id then cnt=1;
  else cnt+1;
  if cnt=3 then output;
run;
```

Comment: This only keeps the third row with 3 duplicate id. How do i keep all three rows with same id?

Comment: To get all rows that match - you can just merge back to your original data set.